# what is the difference between p .classname{} and .classname p{} in css?

Tags: html, css

I need a paragraph to be in red in color?

1. p .target{color:red;font-size:18px};
2. .target p{color:red;font-size:18px};

which one work and how it behaves to rendering HTML doc.

Comment: Why don't you try them out?

Comment: Is this so difficult to find out reading the CSS specs ?

Answer (score 6):

```
p .target{ ... }
```

... means "apply this style to any element with the class `target`, which is inside of a `<p>`".

```
.target p{ ... }
```

... means "apply this style to any element which is a `<p>`, which is inside of an element with class `target`".

Or in general, any CSS of the form:

```
parent child { ... }
```

... will apply the given style to an element of type `child`, as long as it's within a given `parent`.

Comment: And for completeness, `p.target` means "any `<p>` with a class of `target`".

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about 2 different things here.

CSS property is interpreted as `parent child { property}`

Here in example 1, You look for a node with classname `target` in the desendant nodes of a `p` node

```
<div class="target">
  <p>I am in red</p>
</div>
```

In example 2, you are looking for a `p` tag in the descendant nodes of class named `target`

```
<p>
   <span class="target">I am in red now</span>
</p>
```